# output associative array from drop down menu in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, menu

So I am trying to get the year to be echo'd or printed in the output and then the population. So far. I am able to have it print out the population when the option is selected...
However, when I try to have a foreach command in, it prints out nothing. What am I am assuming its because it cannot get the year1 into the variable. 
What am I doing wrong in my code?

Here is my code:

```
 <?php

    if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && isset($_POST['year1'])&& isset ($_POST['year2'])) 
        {
        $year1 = $_POST['year1'];
        $year2 = $_POST['year2'];

        }
function get_years($select)
 {
   $years=array('1790'=>'3929214','1800'=>5236631,'1810'=>7239881,
       '1820'=>9638453,'1830'=>12866020,'1840'=>17069453,
       '1850'=>23161876,'1860'=>31443321,'1870'=>38558371,
       '1880'=>49371340,'1890'=>62979766,'1900'=>76212168,
       '1910'=>92228531,'1920'=>106021568,'1930'=>123202660,
       '1940'=>132165129,'1950'=>151325798,'1960'=>179323175,
       '1970'=>203211926,'1980'=>226545805,'1990'=>248709873,
       '2000'=>281421906,'2010'=>308745538);

   $options='';

   while(list($k,$v)=each($years))
   {
    if($select==$v)
    {
    $options.='<option value="'.$v.'"selected>'.$k.'</option>'; 
    }
    else
    {
    $options.='<option value="'.$v.'">'.$k.'</option>';
    }
   }
   return $options;
 } 
 if(isset($_POST['years']))
 {
  $selected= $_POST['years'];

 }

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Assignment 5 - kpete7</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <h1>US Census Population Change Calculator</h1>

 <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
   <h3>Year 1: <select name="year1" >
  <?php echo get_years($selected); ?>
       </select></h3>

       <h3>Year 2: <select name="year2">
  <?php echo get_years($selected); ?>
       </select></h3>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Calculate">
  </form>

       <?php   
           if (!empty($year1)) {
           if (is_array($year1)) {
           foreach ($year1 as $key_value => $key) {
              echo $key ;
         }
        ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you set years1? I see years and year1 not years1. It seems to be undefined as far as I can see

Comment: years1 is the select value I think. And I set it to the post value

Comment: No, the selected is post[year]. You should know.

Comment: Just to ask....can it only be set to post one time?  I fixed that in my original code. Thank you. Now it just says invalid argument supplied for the foreach statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't really understand how to write it here as text + keep codeblock intact. :)
Is there something similar for php just like jsfiddle?

Moved $years array out of function to use it later.
There were couple variables not set while form was not posted.
Rewrote your function
Used $year1 and $year2 to generate option list and selected values could be different to calcuate population.
Code indentation was scary.

```
$years=array(
    1790 => 3929214,
    1800 => 5236631,
    1810 => 7239881,
    1820 => 9638453,
    1830 => 12866020,
    1840 => 17069453,
    1850 => 23161876,
    1860 => 31443321,
    1870 => 38558371,
    1880 => 49371340,
    1890 => 62979766,
    1900 => 76212168,
    1910 => 92228531,
    1920 => 106021568,
    1930 => 123202660,
    1940 => 132165129,
    1950 => 151325798,
    1960 => 179323175,
    1970 => 203211926,
    1980 => 226545805,
    1990 => 248709873,
    2000 => 281421906,
    2010 => 308745538,
);

if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') && isset($_POST['year1'], $_POST['year2'])) {
    $year1 = (int) $_POST['year1'];
    $year2 = (int) $_POST['year2'];

    echo '<p>Difference of population between selected years: '.abs($year2 - $year1).'</p>';
}
else {
    $year1 = $year2 = reset($years); //default selected
}

function get_years($selected) {
    global $years;
    $options='';
    foreach($years as $k=>$v) {
        $options .= '<option value="'.$v.'"'.($selected==$v ? ' selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$k.'</option>';
    }
    return $options;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Assignment 5 - kpete7</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>US Census Population Change Calculator</h1>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
        <h3>Year 1:
            <select name="year1">
                <?php echo get_years($year1); ?>
            </select>
        </h3>

        <h3>Year 2:
            <select name="year2">
                <?php echo get_years($year2); ?>
            </select>
        </h3>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Calculate">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May I ask how you formulated this code so I understand for next time? You can always tell me to just look it up too...

Comment: Code itself. My main question is the else and then the function part. Why did you use global?

Comment: IF is when you get $year1 and $year2 values from form and then get answer for population.
ELSE is when form was not posted and just get first values from year array.
Global seemed good enough for this small piece of code to access it out of your function.

Comment: Code should be indented with four spaces, text should have no indenting. Double space + enter means new line. Jsfiddle for PHP? I like to use https://3v4l.org